# Send alert notification with series value and rich text format

Tags: grafana

[image]

I saw this grafana test alert notification and would like to do the same for my charts. But I cannot find documentation on how to achieve this. I need to at least show metrics value and an error message if possible

Answer (score 0):

When creating the alert for your dashboard you can specify the alert message.

By default it will send you the value and name of the time-series that triggered the alert.

To enable Grafana to send images you have to set up External Image Storage and enable it in the Notification Channel settings.

Hope this helps

Comment: but how do we format the values say for example if the temperature is 50 which is shown in the dashboard? but in the alert, shows the value as 50.157466522685554